# discord.py can't change the channel's name

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So recently I've tried to create a bot that could change the voice channel's name based on how many members are on the server, but I end up getting this error: `await memberchannel.edit(name = ">> ᴍᴇᴍʙᴇʀꜱ: " + guild.member_count) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit'`

Here's my code, I cannot figure out how to access the .edit attribute:

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = member.guild
    memberchannel : discord.VoiceChannel = get(guild.channels, id=MemberCounterChannel)
    await memberchannel.edit(name = ">> ᴍᴇᴍʙᴇʀꜱ: " + guild.member_count)
```

I did the same thing in the on_member_remove function.

Comment: `MemberCounterChannel` is not a channel id, what is the value of `MemberCounterChannel`? You can search by name with: `get(guild.channels, name='<your_channel_name>')` and use the id from that

Comment: MemberCounterChannel = '716598398001872918'
the problem is my channel is named using a custom font ">> ᴍᴇᴍʙᴇʀꜱ: 3" and I'am not sure if it would work

Comment: I tried doing this: 
`memberchannel : discord.VoiceChannel = get(guild.channels, name=">> ᴍᴇᴍʙᴇʀꜱ: {guild.member_count}")

await memberchannel.edit(name = ">> ᴍᴇᴍʙᴇʀꜱ: " + guild.member_count)` 
but I got the same error

Comment: that won't work, test it with just the current name so you can get the id, then use that id in your code (if this is only for one guild)

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out. after i set id directly, not through the MemberCounterChannel variable it was all about the name, I had to put {0}).format(guild.member_count) instead of + guild.member_count

Comment: you could also use an f-string, `format()` is old school

Answer (score 0):

Events that use `on_member_join` or others related to member events, must require member intents to be enabled. This works to allow these events to run as they are private and should be used carefully.

Intents can be enabled from Discord developer portal, from there you only need to make sure you have enabled `Member` in intents within the "Bot" category. You'd then need to define and use the intents in your bot code in the section you define your bot or client:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='your bot prefix', intents=intents)
```

After you have enabled intents, the member events would work. With your code, `memberchannel` also isn't defined, nor is it a Discord parameter.

This would now get the channel you want to edit by it's ID and edit whenever a user joined to the current member count of the guild the user joined.

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    member_channel = client.get_channel(channel id)
    await member_channel.edit(name=f"Members: {member.guild.member_count}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to toggle all of the intents in my application using discord developers panel and left the code like this (ConfigFile is a json file containing all of the variables):

```py
memberchannel: discord.VoiceChannel = get(guild.channels, id=ConfigFile["MemberCounterChannelID"])
       membercount = guild.member_count - 1
       await memberchannel.edit(name="{0} {1}".format(ConfigFile["MemberCounterChannelName"], membercount))
```

Also I did the `membercount = guild.member_count - 1` part because I only use this bot on my server and it's not made for commercial use so I don't really need it to actually count member-bots